# Jquery Change form action on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.
and I want to change the form action on a submit button. So here is my code but does not change anything at all !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#awardProductsButton').click(function(){
       $('#devicesFormId').attr('action', 'test');
    });
</script>

<form:form commandName="devicesForm" name="devicesForm" id="devicesFormId" method="post"     
action="${contextPath}/newdesign/manage/devices/${devicesForm.devices.id" htmlEscape="yes" enctype="multipart/form-data">   

<button id="awardProductsButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">AWARD product/s</button>

 </form:form>
```

I also tried

```
$('#awardProductsButtonId').submit(function(event){
            alert ('test');
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#deviceFormId').attr('action', '${contextPath}/newdesign/manage/device/${deviceForm.device.id}');
        });
```

but even the alert does not show up

Comment: did u try removing `type="submit"` attribuite from `button` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375144/jquery-prevent-default-then-continue-default

Comment: Your code works. https://jsfiddle.net/qc1fo7wq/

Comment: Well every time you click the button  you prevented the submission, changed the action. You then need to actually submit the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - prevent default, then continue default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375144/jquery-prevent-default-then-continue-default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need  `event.preventDefault()` and `.submit` [read-more](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#devicesFormId').submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault()
       $('#devicesFormId').attr('action', 'test');
       //$(this).attr('action', 'test');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just curious..why wouldn't this become an infinite loop? Wouldn't the form just keep resubmitting?

Comment: Well the form doesn't submit at all now (due to `preventDefault`).. Only the action attribute is changed. There will be  recursion if you also include `.submit()` indeed.