# How can I return a href link to it's default behavior after using e.preventDefault();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I updated my code and rephrased my question:

I am trying to create the following condition. When a link with an empty href attribute (for example href="") is clicked, a modal is launched and the default behavior of that link is prevented..

But when the href attribute contains a value (href="www.something.com") I would like for the link to work as it normally does using its default behavior.

For some reason my code isn't working.  Any help is appreciated.

```
      // Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
      // Encapsulation
      // $ is assigned to jQuery
      ;(function($) {
           // DOM Ready
          $(function() {

              // Binding a click event
              // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
              $('.launch').bind('click', function(e) {
                var attrId = $(this).attr('attrId');

                if( $('.launch').attr('href') == '') {

                    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                    $('div[attrId="' + attrId+'"]').bPopup({
                      //position: ['auto', 'auto'], //x, y
                      appendTo: 'body'
                    });
                }  else {
                  $(this).removeAttribute('attrId');
                  return true;
                }  

              });

          });

      })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things: `event` is undefined, as your event object is simply called `e`. Secondly, `e.stopPropagation();` will not do what you want. `stopPropagation` simply prevents parent events from firing (eg: clicking a `<td>` will also fire click on the containing `<tr>` unless stopped).

Try just replacing your else statement with

```
return true;
```

Also your jQuery is incorrect (as stated in the other answer here).

This answer may help as well:

[How to trigger an event after using event.preventDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I see that I used event instead of e. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery is... very wrong. `$('href').attr('')` is getting the empty attribute from an element `<href>`... Did you mean:

```
if( $(this).attr('href') == '')
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks

Comment: I rephrased my question and code so I still need help on why it's not working