# How can I trigger a div after e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXkoYp

Hello I am trying to trigger this popup after the line, I need this line to stop the page from anchoring

```
         e.preventDefault();
```

I have tried to trigger it using this below but nothing shows up

```
        $('div#popup1').trigger('click');
```

The expected result is this
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXbvXZ

Comment: What is expected result of triggering `click` at `div#popup1` element?

Comment: I have edited with a result. basically something pops up

Comment: How would "something", i.e.g.; `div#popup1` "popup"?

Comment: by clicking the a tag

Comment: Run your `.trigger()` first. Put `e.preventDefault()` at the bottom instead.

Comment: instead of use `:target` to trigger the modal why don't just use the basic way add-remove a class ? or show -hide with jquery

Comment: It seems that your approach is quite strange. You use link but don't want anchoring... Why don't you just make some kind of popup programmatically (setting style, position or class) and open it with some button?

Comment: @Tanmango wouldn't that just open a window and not a popup div? maybe i am thinking about it wrong but how would you make a popup div in an anchor?

Comment: @Danip thank you i was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

it helps maybe: [Stackoverflow question from '11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault)

Comment: If you're just going to link to another question, flag it as a duplicate. Link-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onclick` event attribute at `div#popup1` element, `e.preventDefault()`, add `click` event at `div#popup`, set `.overlay` `.css()` `opacity` to `1` at `div#popup1` click event handler. Not certain how to update codepen

```
$("#stopRed").on("click",function(e){
    $("div#popup1").trigger('click');
});

$("div#popup1").click(function() {
  $(".overlay").css("opacity", 1)
});
```