# Prevent Page Reload after Showing Modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I have this function :

```
$('button[name="submitbutton"]').click(function() {
        var button = 0;
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 0) {
            $('.modal.hapus').modal({
                closable : false,
                onDeny : function(){

                },
                onApprove : function(){
                    $('.form.update').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert("button : 1");
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "katalog/kelolaPerubahan/1",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function(res) {
                                updateRow(res, '<?php echo base_url(); ?>');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }).modal('show');
        } else {
            $('.form.update').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(button);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "katalog/kelolaPerubahan/" + button,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(res) {
                        updateRow(res, '<?php echo base_url(); ?>');
                    }
                });
            })

        }

    })
```

I have two button in my form, with different value. When the button value I clicked is not equal to 0, it looks good, and do the submit action as it should. But, when the value is 0, my goal is showing a modal that contain two option, cancel or ok. But, when the modal is showing, the page is reloading. How can I prevent this reload and wait until two option (cancel or ok) is choosen?

Comment: This page may be helpful [How to trigger an event after using event.preventDefault()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after two days I get what I want, when the modal is showing, javascript will get what user want.

```
$('button[name="submitbutton"]').click(function(event) {
        var button = 0;
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 0) {

            $('.form.update').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var datahapus = $(this).serialize();

                $('.modal.hapus').modal({
                    closable : false,
                    onDeny : function(){

                    },
                    onApprove : function(){
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "katalog/kelolaPerubahan/1",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: datahapus,
                            success: function(res) {
                                updateRow(res, '<?php echo base_url(); ?>');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).modal('show');
            });
        } else {
            $('.form.update').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(button);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "katalog/kelolaPerubahan/" + button,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(res) {
                        updateRow(res, '<?php echo base_url(); ?>');
                    }
                });
            })

        }
    })
```

When the value is 0, form will submit value and I prevent the event to show to modal, when user choose to do what the modal said, javascript execute ajax action.

Thank a lot for all your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You page is reloading because you don't have a `e.preventDefault()` action on the `submitbutton`, and it doesn't wait for you to click OK on Modal and reloades the page.

Try this:

```
$('button[name="submitbutton"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = 0;
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 0) {
            $('.modal.hapus').modal({
                closable : false,
                onDeny : function(){

                },
                onApprove : function(){
                    $('.form.update').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert("button : 1");
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "katalog/kelolaPerubahan/1",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function(res) {
                                updateRow(res, '<?php echo base_url(); ?>');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }).modal('show');
        } else {
            $('.form.update').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(button);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "katalog/kelolaPerubahan/" + button,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(res) {
                        updateRow(res, '<?php echo base_url(); ?>');
                    }
                });
            })

        }

    })
```

or else specify the type of `submitbutton` to be button like

```
<button name = "submitbutton" type="button">Click</button>
```

because if you dont mention it explicitly its default type is `submit` and hence your page reloades.

Comment: That is correct but mind it, this code is registering submit event everytime when modal opens.....!

Comment: yes, it is working.. but the submit action is not working anymore

Comment: Can you do a console.log in  `$('.form.update').submit(function(e){` in onApprove function that will check if it is coming in the call or not

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` within your submit event:

```
$('.form.update').submit(function(e){

    // submit form information through ajax...

    return false; // stop form from refreshing page
});
```

Comment: when I add `return false`, all of my code is not working

Comment: yeah, my apologies. I added it to the wrong block of JavaScript lol. One moment...

Comment: @imilah try now :-)

Comment: still, the page is reloading