# Prevent redirect/ refresh after submit in popup window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, popup

I'm trying to make a **login and signup form** in the same popup window and the problem is, when I press `login` button or `signup` button, it just closes the popup window.

I want the popup window to stay open **even if `login` or `signup` button is clicked**. And I want it to display error or success message within the popup window. The error message does show up in the popup window if there is any error. But the popup window closes after submit, therefore, I have to reopen the popup window and check if there is any error message.

Also, I made a popup window in the header. And the popup window is only visible when `show login` button is clicked.

**header.php**

```
<input type="button" id="show_login" value="Show Login">

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])){

            $username = $_POST['username1'];
            $password = $_POST['password1'];

            if(isset($_POST['username1'])){ 
                $_SESSION['username1'] = $username;
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit;

            } else {
                $error[] = 'Wrong username or password';
            }
        }
    ?>
        <div id="popupLogin">
        <div class="x">CLOSE</div>

        <form id="loginForm" name="login" action="#" method="post">

            <div>LOGIN</div>

            <div>

            <?php
                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>'; }
                }
            ?>

            </div>

            <input class="c" name="username1" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username1']; } ?>" tabindex="1" />

            <input class="c" name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>

            <button id="btnloginSubmit" type="submit" name="loginSubmit">Log in</button>

            <div id="btnSignup">Sign Up Here</div>

        </form>

    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['signupSubmit'])){

            if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
                $error[] = 'Username is too short.';}

            if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
                $error[] = 'Password is too short.';}

            if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';}
        }
    ?>
        <form id="signupForm" name="registration" method="post"  action="#">

        <div>
            <?php

                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>';}
                }
            ?>
        </div>

            <input class="c" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />

            <input class="c" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" />

            <input class="c" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>

            <button name="signupSubmit" type="submit">Sign up</button>

            <div id="btnLogin">Log in Here</div>    
        </form>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
    <body>
            <p>Welcome!</p>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {

        $("#show_login").click(function(){
            showpopup();
        });

        $(".x").click(function(){
            hidepopup();
        });

        $("#btnSignup").click(function(){
            $("#signupForm").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});
            $("#loginForm").css({"visibility":"hidden","display":"none"});
        });

        $("#btnLogin").click(function(){
            $("#loginForm").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});
            $("#signupForm").css({"visibility":"hidden","display":"none"});
        });
    });

    function showpopup()
    {
     $("#popupLogin").fadeIn();
     $("#popupLogin").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});
     $("#signupForm").css({"visibility":"hidden","display":"none"});
    }

    function hidepopup()
    {
     $("#popupLogin").fadeOut();
     $("#popupLogin").css({"visibility":"hidden","display":"none"});
     $("#loginForm").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});

     //the code below does not work
     $('#signupForm').submit(function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data) {
            console.log('success!')
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    }
```

Comment: When your page reloads do you get a hash in your url? `http://someurl.com/#` ? If so, it might be your method hash attribute on your form element.

Comment: @GarrettSanderson yes it does. after clicking "sign up" button, i get a hash at the end of the url like this: "index.php#" but even though I set  action = " " for the form tag, it removes the hash but it still closes the popup window box

Comment: You may need to call `e.preventDefault();` on the first line inside of your submit function? Before you declare the variables.

Comment: Checkout this post, may be of help for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this :

```
     $('#signupForm').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function(data) {
        console.log('success!')
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thank you. I have one more question, if I wanted to validate form, how can I achieve that by using ajax?

Comment: What kind of validation you want?

Comment: username and email validations using if statements, such as `if (name =="") {do someting}`. how do I do it with ajax?

Comment: thank you for your effort however I do know how to validate forms. I just don't know how to validate the form and submit the form with ajax at the same time. please have a look at my code [link](https://jsbin.com/dipekojimi/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: it seems like it is the same code that I've written could you provide the link please