# Turn boolean to false in order to stop event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript

I have a form where the user needs to write their first name, last name, email address, and phone number. The user has to be based in the UK for this to work.

I have no problem preventing the form to be submitted if the inputs are blank or the format is not correct, however, I cannot submit the form successfully once all the input values are correct.

I know it has something to do with my `stopSubmit` code, but I can't seem to turn `true` into `false` once all the input values are correct.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function () {
let theForm = document.getElementById("form");
theForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    let stopSubmit = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < theForm.elements.length; i++) {
        cleanUpErrors();
        if (!checkFirstName(theForm.elements[0])) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
        if (!checkLastName(theForm.elements[1])) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
        if (!checkEmail(theForm.elements[2])) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
        if (!checkPhone(theForm)) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
    }
    if (stopSubmit) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    }, false)
}

function checkFirstName(input) {
    let elemPos = document.getElementById("firstName");
    let inputValue = input.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (inputValue === null || inputValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        if (inputValue.length < 3) {
            errorMessage = "This field has less than 3 characters.";
        }
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
}

function checkLastName(input) {
    let elemPos = document.getElementById("lastName");
    let inputValue = input.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (inputValue === null || inputValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        if (inputValue.length < 3) {
            errorMessage = "This field has less than 3 characters.";
        }
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
}

function checkEmail(input) {
    let elemPos = document.getElementById("email");
    let emailValue = input.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    let regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (!emailValue.match(regex)) {
        errorMessage = "Not a valid email address.";
    }
    if (emailValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
}

function checkPhone(input) {
    let elemPos = input.phone;
    let phoneValue = input.phone.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    let regex = /^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$/;
    if (!phoneValue.match(regex)) {
        errorMessage = "Not a valid UK phone number.";
    }
    if (phoneValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
}

function renderErrorMessage(selectedElem, errorMessage) {
    let errorElem = document.createElement("span");
    errorElem.setAttribute("class", "error");
    let errorText = document.createTextNode(errorMessage);
    errorElem.appendChild(errorText);
    selectedElem.parentNode.insertBefore(errorElem, selectedElem.nextSibling);
    return selectedElem;
}

function cleanUpErrors() {
    let indicator = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (let i = 0; i < indicator.length; i++) {
        indicator[i].setAttribute("class", "hide");
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Personal Information Form</title>
    <script src="scripts/test5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="test3success.html" novalidate="novalidate">
    <label for="firstName">First Name (required)</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" name="text" required>

    <label for="lastName">Last Name (required)</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" name="text" required>

    <label for="email">Email (required)</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" required>

    <label for="phone">Phone Number (required)</label>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" required>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `!checkFirstName(theForm.elements[0])` doesn't return true or false

Comment: None of them return anything. Also the test for the phone number is wrong (`!checkPhone(theForm)`). And why the loop?

Comment: Take a look here:
[Continue after preventdefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checks need to return `true` or `false` considering you are evaluating these within `if` statements.

So, when you are doing

`if (!checkFirstName(theForm.elements[0])) {`

This evaluates to

`if (!undefined) {`

Since `checkFirstName` (and the others) return nothing (`undefined`), which means `stopSubmit` is always set to `true`

Note: There are cleaner ways to do this, I just did a check for `errorMessage` being blank.

Also as pointed out in the comments, you are passing the entire form to the `checkPhone` function, when you could just pass the input as you are doing with the other checks.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let theForm = document.getElementById("form");
  theForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    let stopSubmit = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < theForm.elements.length; i++) {
        cleanUpErrors();
        if (!checkFirstName(theForm.elements[0])) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
        if (!checkLastName(theForm.elements[1])) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
        if (!checkEmail(theForm.elements[2])) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
        if (!checkPhone(theForm)) {
            theForm.elements[i].style.borderColor = "#990000";
            stopSubmit = true;
        }
    }
    if (stopSubmit) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('default prevented')
    }
    }, false)
}

function checkFirstName(input) {
    let elemPos = document.getElementById("firstName");
    let inputValue = input.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (inputValue === null || inputValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        if (inputValue.length < 3) {
            errorMessage = "This field has less than 3 characters.";
        }
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
    if (errorMessage !== "") {
       return false
    }
    
    return true
    
}

function checkLastName(input) {
    let elemPos = document.getElementById("lastName");
    let inputValue = input.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (inputValue === null || inputValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        if (inputValue.length < 3) {
            errorMessage = "This field has less than 3 characters.";
        }
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
    if (errorMessage !== "") {
       return false
    }
    
    return true
}

function checkEmail(input) {
    let elemPos = document.getElementById("email");
    let emailValue = input.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    let regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (!emailValue.match(regex)) {
        errorMessage = "Not a valid email address.";
    }
    if (emailValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
    if (errorMessage !== "") {
       return false
    }
    
    return true
}

function checkPhone(input) {
    let elemPos = input.phone;
    let phoneValue = input.phone.value;
    let errorMessage = "";
    let regex = /^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$/;
    if (!phoneValue.match(regex)) {
        errorMessage = "Not a valid UK phone number.";
    }
    if (phoneValue === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is empty.";
    }
    renderErrorMessage(elemPos, errorMessage);
    
    if (errorMessage !== "") {
       return false
    }
    
    return true
}

function renderErrorMessage(selectedElem, errorMessage) {
    let errorElem = document.createElement("span");
    errorElem.setAttribute("class", "error");
    let errorText = document.createTextNode(errorMessage);
    errorElem.appendChild(errorText);
    selectedElem.parentNode.insertBefore(errorElem, selectedElem.nextSibling);
    return selectedElem;
}

function cleanUpErrors() {
    let indicator = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (let i = 0; i < indicator.length; i++) {
        indicator[i].setAttribute("class", "hide");
    }
}
```

```css
label, .error, button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="test3success.html" novalidate="novalidate">
    <label for="firstName">First Name (required)</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" name="text" required>

    <label for="lastName">Last Name (required)</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" name="text" required>

    <label for="email">Email (required)</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" required>

    <label for="phone">Phone Number (required)</label>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" required>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I've removed the for loop and corrected the `checkPhone` code. It's working, but I'll obviously try to make it more elegant. Again, thank you.