# How can I detect a key up / down event anywhere in an element?

Tags: javascript, html

If I'm in a `textarea`, I can do something like:

```
    if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      e.preventDefault()      return
    }
```

it detects within the textarea, but I want it to bubble up to some parent element. How can I do that?

Comment: It does bubble up unless you're specifically preventing it to do so. If you're having problems receiving the event in a parent element, you'll have to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event bubbles by default unless you use `e.stopPropagation()`:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
});

document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log('Bubbled');
});
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Now if I understand you correctly, you want to prevent the default behavior on the element which has fired the event, but not on the parent elements.

In your particular use case, I guess you want to preserve the scroll behavior of the up and down arrows, but I'm afraid it's not possible for two reasons:

- The [`defaultPrevented`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented) property of a DOM event is read only and there is no such method as `restoreDefault`: [How to trigger an event after using event.preventDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault#answer-7610931)
- If you manually fire a new event, it will not generate the default action associated with that event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling_prior_to_Gecko_5.0

So you have to implement a scroll behavior yourself (which will result in a strange behavior for most users, in my opinion).

Comment: I want to stop the default event on the textarea but not the higher level element.

Comment: I've edited my answer, let me know if it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

You can just put an onKeyPress on a div parent element as long as the textarea is the grand child and you are not doing the `event.stopPropagation()`

```
<div onkeypress="keyPress(event)">
<textarea>sample text area</textarea>
</div>

<script>
function keyPress(event) {
  alert(event.keyCode);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're writing JSX btw

Comment: thanks @GuerricP for letting me know, I edited my answer