# Calling a script to save form data in google sheets from django app using js

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I am making a web app and I have one form in it. I want to store the data that a person enters, in the form to be mapped in google sheets. The script successfully saves the data onto the sheet but upon saving I am redirecting the user to a new page. The problem is when I attach the code of data mapping, the redirection doesn't work but if I comment the code where I am calling the script, the redirection starts working.

```
# here is the code where i have made the form in HTML file using crispyforms
<form method="POST" id="submit_info" class="bg-light p-4 p-md-5 contact-form" name="google-sheet">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form|crispy}}

          <div class="form-group text-center">
              <input type="submit"  value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary center py-3 px-5">
          </div>
</form>
```

This is the js code that executes to save the data onto google sheets

```
<script>
          const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwN9jxAQwA9f7qF_tvUbpuRpIhObeAJT8nAqwIRrDZYMPqbyf6j/exec'
          const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
          form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})})

</script>
```

This is the code where I am handling the redirection and saving in django views.py file:

```
def store(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('thankYouPage') # a second webpage where user should be redirected
else:
    form = ContactForm()
return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` in your script basically stop you from calling the POST request

Comment: @LinhNguyen thanks a lot for your answer. so what could be done here. I mean is there any substitute here?

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610871/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-using-event-preventdefault