# How to open content in a new tab using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python + Selenium.

Browsing this page

https://rovo.co/explore/activities

you will see many activities.

Using Python + Selenium, how can I open each activity in a new tab, and switch to the new tab?

I tried the following code, but it doesn't open in a new tab.

```
link = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-vurnku")[0]))

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.click(on_element=link)
actions.perform()
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I see you've added a bounty. Can you explain why Jakobs answer does not suffice and what needs to be different for you to accept the answer?

Comment: In Selenium 4, just use driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')

Comment: @thetaco I am still struggling to get Jakobs codes to run on my computer. It throws a bunch of errors on my computer. Actually my setup is very basic, I didn't configure anything out of the ordinary I think, so not too sure why there are errors.

Comment: @browsermator Can you please provide code snippet how to do it? I am new to Python and Selenium. Thanks.

Comment: that's it right there... then the driver will be in the new tab and you can navigate to the site and click your link(s)

Comment: @browsermator Where is it? Let me explain again what I need to achieve. Open the activities page in the 1st tab. This only happens ONE time, and in the 1st tab only. Then, opens activity 1 in tab 2. Then, opens activity 2 in tab 3. Then, opens activity 3 in tab 4, ... Notice, the activities page stays open in tab 1 and is never opened in other tabs.

Comment: just use driver.get(desired_activity_url) after driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')  If you need to you can get the href of the link before.

Comment: @browsermator The problem now is how do we figure out what is the URL of the activity?

Comment: you can use get_attribute("href") on the link element to get the link.

Comment: There is no obvious href element... the page is a bit complicated, I do not see any obvious href element. Please check and inspect the activities page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script that goes to that site and opens up the first 20 activities in new tabs.

`pip install seleniumbase`, and run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB() as sb:  # By default, browser="chrome" if not set.
    sb.open("https://rovo.co/explore/activities")
    for i in range(20):
        sb.open_new_tab(switch_to=True)
        sb.open("https://rovo.co/explore/activities")
        sb.wait_for_element("div.css-uq1pv2")
        sb.find_elements("div.css-uq1pv2")[i].click()
        sb.sleep(0.25)
    breakpoint()
```

Comment: Can we open https://rovo.co/explore/activities in the first tab, then open each activity in a new tab? The reason I wanna do this is because, I will actually need to scroll down the activities page to lazy load more activities, then only open each activity in a new tab, scrap some info, and close the tab.

Comment: That’s exactly what the above script does. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have already tried the above script, it is not doing what I want. The above script opens a new tab, opens the activities page in this new tab, then opens an activity in this new tab, then repeats. This is not what I want, although eventually the end result may seem like what I want. What I really want is this --> Open the activities page in the 1st tab. This only happens ONE time, and in the 1st tab only. Then, opens activity 1 in tab 2. Then, opens activity 2 in tab 3. Then, opens activity 3 in tab 4, ... Notice, the activities page stays open in tab 1 and is never opened in other tabs.

Comment: On that page, it doesn't give you the URL for an activity until after you've already clicked on it. So you would need to inject JS into the page to do an `event.preventDefault()` so that you can try to grab the URL without leaving the page, and then open the activity page in a new URL. That sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610871/7058266

Comment: I have no clue how to inject JS into the page and do all that. Could you please provide code snippet to achieve that?

Comment: For executing JS with Selenium Python: `driver.execute_script(script)`. With SeleniumBase: `sb.driver.execute_script(script)`. As for the script you need, you should check with the people from stackoverflow.com/q/7610871/7058266 who know the JS details best.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like cumbersome, lengthy code. This is one of the reason why I created the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package as an extension to Selenium so you don't have to hassle with `ActionChains` and other details.

Find more information about [methods to open tabs and windows in the documentation](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/reference/browser/window/open/).

Maybe something like this would work?

```py
from browserist import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.window.open.new_tab("https://example.com", "tab_1")
    browser.window.open.new_tab("https://google.com", "tab_2")
    browser.window.switch_to("tab_1")
```

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier.

Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

Also, note that you often don't need explicit or implicit waits like `WebDriverWait` when using [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/). Before interacting with any element, it simply waits for it to be active, which leads to leaner, more efficient code. For instance, you only need this to click a button:

```py
    browser.click.button("//*[@class='css-vurnku'][1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would solve this with the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) extension of the Selenium web driver. It simply makes browser automation much easier.

Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

How I would solve your problem:

Normally you would get a list of activity URLs from the `<a href="https://example.com">...</a>` tags, but since Rovo is a web application, it doesn't expose the links in the HTML. Instead we need to click and open each activity to get its URL. That's the first iteration, and hereafter we open each URL in a new tab.

```py
from browserist import Browser

activities_url = "https://rovo.co/explore/activities"
activities_xpath = "//*[@id='bp3-tab-panel_explore-tabs_activities']/div/div"
activity_clickable_partial_xpath = "/div/div[1]"

with Browser() as browser:
    activity_links: list[str] = []

    browser.open.url(activities_url)
    number_of_activities = browser.tool.count_elements(activities_xpath)

    for i in range(1, number_of_activities + 1):
        browser.click.button(f"{activities_xpath}[{i}]{activity_clickable_partial_xpath}")
        browser.wait.until.url.contains("https://rovo.co/plays/")
        activity_links.append(browser.get.url.current())
        browser.back()

    for i, link in enumerate(activity_links):
        browser.window.open.new_tab(link, f"tab_{i + 1}")
```

Excerpt of how it works:

[image: Browserist automation in action]

Comment: I installed the package with pip install browserist, then I have the following
browser = Browser()
    browser.open.url("https://rovo.co/explore/activities")

Comment: I get the following error: 

 return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "D:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
  File "D:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    w.start()

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the error I get from Browserist 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mLG0.gif

Comment: I haven’t seen this issue before. Seems like you’re running Python 3.10, right? Maybe a quick fix would be trying with newer versions 3.11 or 3.12?

Comment: Find more mitigation options here: https://github.com/jakob-bagterp/browserist/issues/517